# haml and sass syntax highlight in smultron

Tags: macos, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way I could get syntax highlight to work for haml and sass in Smultron?
I know there's a bundle to do this in Textmate, but I would like to have it in Smultron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely. Go to your Smultron file

Smultron.app > right-click > Show package content > Content > Resources > Syntax

Then choose anyfile already existing (Standard.plist is empty so good to use, creating a new one will not work), double-click and change the syntax inside. Pretty straight forward (if you have the Property List Editor from the Developer Tools for Mac so I guess I don't need to give some explanations here. Else, some XML knowledge is required but nothing crazy...

Take care...